# LOB application with Aurelia Vs WPF

Tags: aurelia

I'm working on a WPF project that uses Microsoft Ribbon control, docking panel. The app is very similar to the Visual Studio IDE. The user can open multiple documents and work on it. They will all open as multiple documents in different windows as MDIs. Any state change made on one document can be seen on the other immediately. The technology being used are Prism 5.0, DevExpress MVVM and controls.

There are few reasons to move away from the WPF application due to the lack of availability of the developers and to reach more devices and not just windows.

My questions are:

1. Does Aurelia provide event aggregation as in Prism, so a subscriber in one module which has Screen B can be notified from a publisher in another module which has Screen A? As an example, I have two screen open. One screen is the *customer and his orders* and the other is the *shipping*. When I ship the order on the shipping screen, the order status of the customer on the other screen will be immediately updated?
2. Can Aurelia be used to data bind [HTML 5 DevExpress controls](http://js.devexpress.com/WebDevelopment/MultiPurpose/)?
3. Does Aurelia provide type safety?
4. Is Aurelia suitable for building financial LOB applications where rich UX and complex UI are the requirements? The main requirement of a LOB application is multi document interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, Aurelia has an EventAggregator. You can see an example of its use in this demo app: https://github.com/aurelia/app-contacts
2. It looks like the DevExpress controls utilize knockout for data binding. Aurelia's binding engine can be taught to work with Knockout. Here is an example adapter: https://github.com/jdanyow/aurelia-knockout
3. Aurelia is written in ES6/7 and does not provide type safety. We have .d.ts files to use with TypeScript. Or are you wanting runtime type safety?
4. Aurelia should be well suited to this type of application.

Comment: To answer your question on type safety, what I'm looking for is compile time safety. I assume compile time type safety can't be provided by ES6/7 unless being used with typescript.